# Can anyone explain how this code can be converted to work on a Arduino Uno

Tags: arduino-uno, programming, compile

I was hoping someone could help, im totally new to this. I wish to use this code for a Raspberry Pi on an Arduino Uno with the Adafruit SD data logging shield. It is for recording reed switch closures on a tipping bucket rain gauge. The interrupt and bounce time are to allow program interrupts and false tip suppression. I am looking to tie it in with the RTC and SD storage options on the Arduino. Any help appreciated.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time

# this many mm per bucket tip
CALIBRATION = 0.200
# which GPIO pin the gauge is connected to
PIN = 17
# file to log rainfall data in
LOGFILE = "log.csv"

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)  
GPIO.setup(PIN, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)

# variable to keep track of how much rain
rain = 0

# the call back function for each bucket tip
def cb(channel):
    global rain
    rain = rain + CALIBRATION

# register the call back for pin interrupts
GPIO.add_event_detect(PIN, GPIO.FALLING, callback=cb, bouncetime=300)

# open the log file
file = open(LOGFILE, "a")

# display and log results
while True:
    line = "%i, %f" % (time.time(), rain)
    print(line)
    file.write(line + "\n")
    file.flush()
    rain = 0
    time.sleep(5)

# close the log file and exit nicely
file.close()
GPIO.cleanup()
```

Comment: What have you tried? What part of it are you having problems with? If you don't know where to start then start at the very beginning - don't try and do it all at once. Get the Arduino to (for example) light up an LED when the reed switch closes, and build up from there. Read tutorials on how to read inputs. Read examples on how to deal with RTC and SD. We aren't a code conversion service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should help get you started but don't expect it to actually work as it is. Note that i did not test this at all, it's for example purposes.  if there is a specific programming problem it should be addressed separately instead of handing out working code.

```
const int CALIBRATION = 0.200;   //Calibration Constant
int pin = 2;                     //Pin it's on, this is int0 for uno.
volatile int rain = 0;           //Used in interrupt routine

void setup() {
    Serial.begin(9600);
    pinMode(pin, INPUT);
    attachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(pin), cn, FALLING);
}

void loop() {

     /* Output OR LOG DATA HERE
        Also You need a Time Library and RTC (Real Time CLock) the above
        code is for a raspberry pi that has all that. */

}

void cb() {
    rain = rain + CALIBRATION;
}
```